# Implement PrincipalExtractor for facebook (spring boot with social)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to implement social login for a spring boot application. I am using Spring Boot version 1.4.2. the application uses spring security so I opted to use the `@EnableOAuthSso` annotation on `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. I am using Facebook as the OAuth provider

my application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.social.facebook.appId=12345678976543
spring.social.facebook.appSecret=a4179c05880d948cd6c05806a4179d7c
security.oauth2.client.client-id= 12345678976543
security.oauth2.client.client-secret= a4179c05880d948cd6c05806a4179d7c
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri= https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri= https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
security.oauth2.client.token-name= oauth_token
security.oauth2.client.authentication-scheme= query
security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme= form
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri= https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

The recommended way to set the `principal` is to implement the `PrincipalExtractor` interface.

My Immplementation looks like this:

```
@Bean
public PrincipalExtractor principalExtractor(Facebook facebook, UserRepository userRepository) {
    return new PrincipalExtractor() {
        @Override
        public Object extractPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map) {   
            String facebookId = (String) map.get("id");     
            User u= userRepository.findByFacebookId(facebookId);

            if (u== null) {
                org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User user = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile(facebookId);
                u= new User();
                u.setEmail(user.getEmail());
                u.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
                u.setLastName(user.getLastName());
                u.setFacebookId(facebookId);
                userRepository.save(u);
            }
            return u;
        }
    };
```

When I run this It redirect the user to the facebook authorization page, BUT when facebook redirects back to the application (This is where the PrincipalExtractor#extractPrincipal  is invoked ), the line:

```
org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User user = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile(facebookId);
```

throw the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.facebook' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/social/FacebookAutoConfiguration$FacebookConfigurerAdapter.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook]: Factory method 'facebook' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.connectionRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/social/config/annotation/SocialConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository]: Factory method 'connectionRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:44) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.userOperations(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.commerceforge.estore.config.SocialSecurityConfig$2.extractPrincipal(SocialSecurityConfig.java:115) ~[main/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices.getPrincipal(UserInfoTokenServices.java:115) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices.extractAuthentication(UserInfoTokenServices.java:97) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices.loadAuthentication(UserInfoTokenServices.java:93) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at 

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook]: Factory method 'facebook' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.connectionRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/social/config/annotation/SocialConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository]: Factory method 'connectionRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
```

That means that the framework cannot create the `Facebook` bean because there is no user signed in!

This happen after the user authorize the aplication on facebook site and redirected back to my application, so theoretically there is a signed in user, I do not exactly know how or when the framework get this information.

This is how I implemented it, Not sure what is wrong,

Please let me know how to implement it right to get the User Profile data (`org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User`)

What is the recommended way to implement `PrincipalExtractor` for Facebook?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hello I know it's 2 monhts old but maybe somebody will find post looking for similar answer

The reason you got this exception is because spring social connection is different, than you have using oath.
What you need is as follows: Get token from existing connection from authentication ( of course secure with instanceof etc.)

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String token = ((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails()).getTokenValue();
```

And then you can get data with spring.social.facebook like this:

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token);
if (facebook.isAuthorized()) {
        String[] fields = {"id", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "cover"};
        User userProfile = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
        byte[] userProfileImage = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfileImage();
        //rest of stuff
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `getAuthentication()` is actually null for me in this case when used in the PrincipalExtractor - any idea why this might be?

Comment: If `getAuthentication()` is null , ensure that your spring security config is correct, and you are in fact correctly logging in with OAuth. The value of authentication in security context  should be at least AnonymousAuthentication

Comment: Figured out the problem. When setting a principalExtractor manually on a tokenService, the extractor is called during the building of the Authentication object.  The solution is to instead inject the OAuth2ClientContext and get the token there instead.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to set your `user-info-uri` to something like this:

```
userInfoUri=https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email
```

Then you can access the data inside your `PrincipalExtractor` without the need of the Authentication context:

```
@Override
public Object extractPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map) {
    String facebookId = (String) map.get("id");
    String name = (String) map.get("name");
    String email = (String) map.get("email");
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the Authentication object might not yet be available.  You can instead inject `OAuth2ClientContext` and get the token you need to access the identity provider, in this case Facebook.

```
@Autowired
private OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext;
...
String token = oAuth2ClientContext.getAccessToken().getValue();
Facebook fbApi = new FacebookTemplate(token);
```